# Do not consider field, field-formatter and entity-reference tags as a synonym of entities

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I recently noticed that tags [field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field), [field-formatter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-formatter), and [entity-reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-reference) have recently all been marked as a synonym of the [entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity) tag.

To the extend it is needed, here are my 2 cents about how I understand those Drupal thingies:

- an ***entity*** (introduced as of D7) is something to represent a user, a node, a group, a message, etc. If you're familiar with a relational DBMS, it's the equivalent of a ***table***.
- an ***field*** is typically some sort of "attribute" to provide more details about an entity, something to represent a name, a location, a date, a color, the key of a related entity, etc. If you're familiar with a relational DBMS, it's the equivalent of a ***column*** of a table.

To continue the comparison with a relational DBMS: saying that "field" is a synonym of an "entity", is like saying that a "column" (of a table) is a synonym of a table. That's for sure not correct (actually completely wrong).

Or to add a Drupal example, if you're familiar with the Rules module, how about Rules Conditions like "*Entity* has *Field*" or "*Entity* is of type". Or Rules Actions like "Fetch *Entity*" (not something like "Fetch *Field*").

Moreover:

- a ***field formatter*** has to do with how the value of some ***field*** is to be formatted (to be displayed), that's not what a ***field*** is about. In Drupal Commerce, prices are stored in fields with values that correspond to *cents*, however when they are shown (in a cart, etc) they are *formatted* as EURs, or USDs, etc, with a separator (comma or point) in front of the last 2 digits.
- an ***entity reference*** is about a link (a pointer) to some entity, something which is actually the key that helps retrieving the entity that the entity reference is pointing to. That's not the same as an ***entity*** itself. In a relational DBMS, this is what a "foreign key" is about.

For all those reasons, please perform an undo of whatever happened to mark the tags [field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field), [field-formatter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-formatter), and [entity-reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-reference) as a synonym of [entities](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entities).

**Update**: some related searches:

- ***591*** [results found containing "entity reference" not tagged with ***entities*** (questions only)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22entity%20reference%22%20-%5Bentities%5D%20is%3Aq).
- ***47*** [results found containing "field formatter" not tagged with ***entities*** (questions only)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Newest&q=%22field%20formatter%22%20-%5Bentities%5D%20is%3Aq).

Comment: I take it the [field formatter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field-formatter) & [entity reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-reference) tags got nuked.

Comment: @NoSssweat no matter what happened to them, at the time I posted this question, for sure they were marked as synonym (and I think they should be restored ...

Comment: Slight non-update on this, but I still haven't gotten to the bottom of what happened here, as it is not clear from the tools I have access to.